# What is "Inline" or "Inline elements/Inline level flow content" in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've seen those terms a lot like in InlineUIContainer, or in a new instance of the Run class, which is a type of Inline. What's an Inline?

Answer (score -1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.inline?view=netframework-4.8

"An abstract class that provides a base for all inline flow content elements."

Currently implemented by the following classes

- [System.Windows.Documents.AnchoredBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.anchoredblock?view=netframework-4.8)
- [System.Windows.Documents.InlineUIContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.inlineuicontainer?view=netframework-4.8)
- [System.Windows.Documents.LineBreak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.linebreak?view=netframework-4.8)
- [System.Windows.Documents.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.run?view=netframework-4.8)
- [System.Windows.Documents.Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.span?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: That doesn't help. What's inline flow content elements?